# How to install a specific file from the npm packages like from bootstrap only bootstrap.min.css?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, npm

I was using the bootstrap.min.css installed from the bootstrap package using npm in react but it made me curious that is there any way so that we can install the specific files from the bootstrap package instead of full package.
Moreover, if we use the specific file in my case only bootstrap.min.css instead of other files from bootstrap package. Does it affect the performance of app.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what part of Bootstrap component, you can.

**CSS**

import scss files in `bootstrap/scss/` that you need in scss file in your project. **you have to use scss file** format for style sheet.

```scss
// Required
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
// Optional
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
...
```

reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/theming/#importing

**JS**

import js file in `bootstrap/js/dist/`.

```js
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/util';
import 'bootstrap/js/dist/alert';
...
```

reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/webpack/#importing-javascript

And using specific component makes you have compact build size and a little bit faster loading speed.